# How do I use social-share-button gem (or any other gem for that matter) in a rails 6 web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

with all the changes in the app/asset folder. I am a little confused as to how i am supposed to follow the instructions on their github page.

Comment: Just because you’re using Rails 6 doesn’t mean you can’t install a gem. What issues are you having?

Comment: don't seem to have app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee in the app and they're instructions me to add the following

#= require social-share-button
#= require social-share-button/wechat # if you need use WeChat

Comment: Add it to `application.js`